# How to develop an API which reads Qr Codes in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, qr-code, multer

I am working on microservice, creating a REST API in node.js using express, I cannot figure out a way to read Qr Codes. How am I supposed to work it out?
P.S I am using zxing library but unable to successfully implement it in my code.

I have tried various solutions including working with alternative libraries but main problem is implementing it.

As I am using my company's system I am not allowed to show all the data here, but I will update the questions with errors soon. 
But in simple words whenever I send a Qr code image it fails to read it.

Comment: have you been able to create a very simple "Proof of concept", that you can share here ? as ZXing is, as far as I know, an open source library(ies), you can build a [mcve] by creating a very simple program to test the library. That would help both yourself and the potential persons here to actually understand and pinpoint your issue.

Comment: My probelm is I cannot email myself the code as I am not authorized to send an email of any documentation. But i will try to update the question as much as I can today.

Comment: I dont want to go to any freelancing sites for help, as I really want to learn to code. If there are any resources to develop an Api with a qr code scanner, it would help me alot.

Comment: you don't need to email yourself any code or bypass any policy. You could try to recreate from scratch a very simple node program that read an image with a qrcode already there, and see if you can at least work this out. Then try to create another very simple node program to upload a file to your server. If one of these tests fail, then the problem is a bit more isolated. If both of your tests succeed, then the problem lies in the "glue" code in between. In any case, that help pinpoint where the problem is. Just asking for tutorials or general guidance is off-topic here, unfortunately.